# Detecting if Browser supports canplaythrough

Tags: video, detect

I've got an issue at the moment, that some browsers do not seem to be playing a video when I wrap the play method inside an eventListener for the "canplaythrough" event.

My Code is

```
document.getElementById('introVideo').addEventListener("canplaythrough", playVideo, false);

function playVideo(){
    document.getElementById('introVideo').play();
    document.getElementById('introVideo').removeEventListener("canplaythrough", playVideo, false);
}
```

However for some reason, Firefox occasionally doesn't play the video and other browsers "sometimes" don't play either, it just sits on the first frame.